# Deploying a Spring Boot Micro Service to an AWS EC2 Beanstalk Instance With an RDS Instance -> Receiving 502 Error

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I have tirelessly tried to deploy my Spring Boot service to an AWS EC2 Beanstalk instance for many days now. I understand there are other questions for this issue; I've tried them all. My application is packaged in a jar file and is then uploaded to Beanstalk via the UI.

Here is an error within a nginx error.log file:

```
[error] 2993#0: *406 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 107.170.237.194, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "3.18.16.198"
```

I'm aware that this is likely caused by the nginx port routing issue. Therefore, like what most have suggested, I have added two additional environmental variables to my configuration within the UI:

```
SERVER_PORT = 5000
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE = beanstalk
```

Here is my application's application.yaml file:

```
server:
  port: 5000

spring:
  profiles: beanstalk, default
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://exampledb.quvvwdp4564o.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/exampleapp
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: testuser
    password: testAnswer!23
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        jdbc:
          lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true
---
spring:
  profiles: unit-test, integration-test
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=PostgreSQL
    username: testuser
    password: testAnswer!23
jpa:
  properties:
    hibernate:
      jdbc:
        lob:
          non_contextual_creation: true

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
```

The reason why I added the SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE variable to the configuration section is because I thought the RDS instance connection details was causing the issue.

Does anybody have any suggestions or knowledge about this topic?

Comment: tell us more about the env setup in beanstalk. Is it java env or docker container ? .

Comment: Great suggestion. Will update. In short, it's a Java env.